# Groovy cast List<List<Integer>> into int[][]

Tags: arraylist, multidimensional-array, groovy, casting

I am embedding Groovy into my game engine and I am invoking this Groovy method from my script to get some information

```
def getSameTiles() {
    final int cx = 0;
    final int cy = 6;

    return  [
                [
                    [cx + 0, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 0, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 0, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 3, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 4, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 3, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 4, cy + 2],
                ],
            ];
}
```

I can do `as List<Integer>[]` but is there an elegant way to turn it into an `int[][]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `*.toArray()` required for each entry in matrix to be an `Object[]`.
- Finally inferring the return as a matrix `Object[][]`.

as shown below

```
def getSameTiles() {
    final int cx = 0
    final int cy = 6

    return  [
                [
                    [cx + 0, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 0],
                    [cx + 0, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 0, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 1, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 2, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 3, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 4, cy + 1],
                    [cx + 3, cy + 2],
                    [cx + 4, cy + 2],
                ]*.toArray()
            ] as Object[][]
}
```